# AngularJS pass object to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Why it's pass null in `model` variable? Where is mistake?

[image]

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult LoginAngular(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(model.UserName);
        return Json(model.UserName,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Angular:

```
var login = angular.module('LoginApp', []);
login.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = 'Login';
    $scope.model = { UserName: 'nothing', Password: 'nothing' };
    $scope.model.UserName = "Test";
    $scope.model.Password = 'Test';
    $scope.returnUrl = '/Account/TestLogin';

    $scope.onClick = function () {
        console.log($scope.model);
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Account/LoginAngular',
            params: { model: $scope.model, returnUrl: $scope.returnUrl }
        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: from my understading "get" is for getting data, "post" is for pushing data so you should change that.  you are also trying to map an angular model to an mvc model.  make sure that the terms defined in your mvc view model match exactly with what you defined in angular

Comment: get request don't have request body, you need and should use POST for operation such as login or registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```
  $http({
        url: '/Account/LoginAngular',
        method: "POST",
        data: {model: $scope.model, returnUrl: $scope.returnUrl},
        headers: {  
            "Content-Type": "application/json"  
        }  
    }).then(function(response) {
        // success
    }, 
    function(response) { // optional
        // failed
    });
```

Alternatively you can try:

```
   $http.post('/Account/LoginAngular',{model: $scope.model, returnUrl: $scope.returnUrl}) 
       .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //get response
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            //get error details
        });
```

Comment: using `$.param()` assumes jQuery is being used and it shouldn't be used for `"application/json" `. angular also has a built in serializer that negates needing `$.param()` if you want to use form encoding. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike

Comment: Noted. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST method to send the data.

```
var login = angular.module('LoginApp', []);
login.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.name = 'Login';
$scope.model = { UserName: 'nothing', Password: 'nothing' };
$scope.model.UserName = "Test";
$scope.model.Password = 'Test';
$scope.returnUrl = '/Account/TestLogin';

$scope.onClick = function () {
    console.log($scope.model);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/LoginAngular?returnUrl=$scope.returnUrl',
        data: $scope.model,
    }).success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
  };
});
```